# MySQL and Python Select Statement

Tags: python, mysql

I'm currently trying to select specific text from a cell within my table, but I can't get MySQL to obey my command. I'm sure I'm doing it wrong, but to me this feels right... I've checked the documentation and Google for this but I wasn't able to come up with an answer myself, hence why I'm turning to you.

This is the outlay of the MySQL:

```
mysql> describe configuration;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| option  | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| setting | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

In PHPMyAdmin it looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+
| option  | setting |
+---------+---------+
| version | 0.7.48  |
+---------+---------+
```

I'm trying this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="XXX", user="XXX", passwd="XXX", db="XX")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT setting FROM configuration WHERE option = version")
current_version = cur.fetchone()
db.close()
cur.close()
```

How come this isn't working? I'm at loss.

Comment: `"SELECT setting FROM configuration WHERE option = 'version'"`

Comment: You need quotes around the word `version`

Comment: @e4c5 version isn't a variable though, and as such, when I put it in quotes, it borks out: _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option = 'version'' at line 1")

Comment: sorry forgot that option is a reserved word too `option`

Comment: it's because version isn't a variable that you need to wrap it in quotes. note it's "`" around option. (backtick)

Comment: As @e4c5 said, you have to wrap column name `option` inside "\`" and `version` inside single quotes, like `\`option\` = 'version'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**e4c5** and **acw1668** are right:

```
cur.execute("SELECT setting FROM configuration WHERE `option` = 'version'")
```

Does the trick.